# Make Certain Html Override other parts of html

Tags: html, css

im trying out some work in 'webydo' but i am running into a problem. i am trying to change one of the breakpoints, switching from pc to tablet view, which normally happens (set by webydo) at 959px screen width. I want it to happen when screen width is 1180. the problem is that i cannot change the code webydo sets for these breakpoints, i can only add extra code. Would it be possible to copy the part of the code webydo generated and change some of it and then set it to some sort of override mode? so that the browser only reads that part? in the code down below, the top part is about the breakpoints

website is braemo.com

```
<div id='skrollr-body'>
```

```
<div id='mainShape24__Shape24_Shape66584'   data-id='mainShape24' class='dataTypeShape  mainShape24    mainShape' data-type='Shape' ></div>

    <header><div id='mainMainRow1' class='dataTypeMainRow mainMainRow1 ' data-type='MainRow'>
        <div id='mainMainContent2' class='dataTypeMainContent mainMainContent2' data-type='MainContent'></div>
    </div></header>
    <main><div id='mainMainRow3' class='dataTypeMainRow mainMainRow3 ' data-type='MainRow'>
        <div id='mainMainContent4' class='dataTypeMainContent mainMainContent4 ContentHeight' data-type='MainContent'>      <div id='innerShape38__Shape38_Shape2550241'   data-id='innerShape38' class='dataTypeShape  innerShape38  fit_to_bg_new  ' data-type='Shape' ></div>
    <a href='http://braemo.com'><div id='innerImage41__Image41' data-id='innerImage41' data-type='Image' class='dataTypeImage  innerImage41   '><img data-image-fitting-type='3' data-image-position-type='' width="150" height="36"   style="position:absolute;width:150;height:36;left:0px;top:0px" alt="Braemo logo" title="Home" src="http://images8.webydo.com/93/9302219/3958%2f58E719CC-635F-2876-7CE1-2449DC82AEA0.png"    ></div></a>
    <div class='dataTypeMenu menu left horizontal innerMenu43 ' data-type='Menu' data-name='Top Menu' id='innerMenu43'><nav>            <ul>
            <li id='mainMenuElement0innerMenu43' data-pageName='features' class='innerMenu43_category image_wa' onmouseover='javascript:MenuOver(this, event, "ltr", "")' onmouseout='javascript:MenuOut(this, event, "")' data-childmenu='' onclick='javascript:menuLiClick(this,event,"features.html","false")'> <A href="features.html" title="Features" class="category">Features</A></li>
            <li id='mainMenuElement1innerMenu43' data-pageName='pricing' class='innerMenu43_category image_wa' onmouseover='javascript:MenuOver(this, event, "ltr", "")' onmouseout='javascript:MenuOut(this, event, "")' data-childmenu='' onclick='javascript:menuLiClick(this,event,"pricing.html","false")'> <A href="pricing.html" title="Pricing" class="category">Pricing</A></li>
            <li id='mainMenuElement2innerMenu43' data-pageName='stories' class='innerMenu43_category image_wa' onmouseover='javascript:MenuOver(this, event, "ltr", "")' onmouseout='javascript:MenuOut(this, event, "")' data-childmenu='' onclick='javascript:menuLiClick(this,event,"stories.html","false")'> <A href="stories.html" title="Stories" class="category">Stories</A></li>
            <li id='mainMenuElement3innerMenu43' data-pageName='contact' class='innerMenu43_category image_wa' onmouseover='javascript:MenuOver(this, event, "ltr", "")' onmouseout='javascript:MenuOut(this, event, "")' data-childmenu='' onclick='javascript:menuLiClick(this,event,"contact.html","false")'> <A href="contact.html" title="Contact" class="category">Contact</A></li>
        </ul>
    </nav></div>
    <div id='innerShape45__Shape45'   data-id='innerShape45' class='dataTypeShape  innerShape45  fit_to_bg_new  ' data-type='Shape' ></div>
    <div id='innerImage46__Image46' data-id='innerImage46' data-type='Image' class='dataTypeImage  innerImage46   '><img data-image-fitting-type='3' data-image-position-type='' width="640" height="511"   style="position:absolute;width:640;height:511;left:0px;top:0px" alt="" title="" src="http://images8.webydo.com/93/9302219/3958%2f0F36F407-2DAD-411B-A7DF-6C7CF678C489.png_650"    ></div>
    <div id='innerMagicWidget50__MagicWidget50' data-widgetkey='1035' data-id='innerMagicWidget50'  class='dataTypeMagicWidget innerMagicWidget50    ' data-type='MagicWidget'><div class="wrapper_innerMagicWidget50_ey"><div class="button_innerMagicWidget50_ey innerMagicWidget50_ey hvr-fade_innerMagicWidget50_ey  "><a class="text_innerMagicWidget50_ey White-Cta-Text">Start Free Trial</a></div></div></div>
    <div id='innerMagicWidget51__MagicWidget51' data-widgetkey='1037' data-id='innerMagicWidget51'  class='dataTypeMagicWidget innerMagicWidget51    ' data-type='MagicWidget'><div class="wrapper_innerMagicWidget51_ey"><div class="button_innerMagicWidget51_ey innerMagicWidget51_ey hvr-fade_innerMagicWidget51_ey  "><a class="text_innerMagicWidget51_ey White-Cta-Text">Start Free Trial</a></div></div></div>
    <div     id='innerText52__Text52' data-id='innerText52' style='' data-type="text" class='dataTypeText  inner_text innerText52   text_editor_resets' ><div  class='innerText52_ContentDiv'><h1 class="Page-Title ospfxw20f30c919e96a52e80de2337a4683edbossfx">Get Your Website. Subscription Based.</h1></div><div class='text_caption_background' style='background-color:transparent;opacity:1;position:absolute;left:0;bottom:0;top:0;right:0;z-index:-1;'></div></div>
    <div     id='innerText53__Text53' data-id='innerText53' style='' data-type="text" class='dataTypeText  inner_text innerText53   text_editor_resets' ><div  class='innerText53_ContentDiv'><p class="Normal ospfxwcaa5bc988d288fe638024caaa5584b46ossfx">A website should not only be well-designed, it needs to convert.&nbsp;Subscription based webdesign helps your business to get the most out of the current day&nbsp;</p></div><div class='text_caption_background' style='background-color:transparent;opacity:1;position:absolute;left:0;bottom:0;top:0;right:0;z-index:-1;'></div></div>
    <div     id='innerText54__Text54' data-id='innerText54' style='' data-type="text" class='dataTypeText  inner_text innerText54   text_editor_resets' ><div  class='innerText54_ContentDiv'><h2 class="Title ospfxw26aa31b7953833af260bf21d1e1bbf49ossfx">Something Important</h2></div><div class='text_caption_background' style='background-color:transparent;opacity:1;position:absolute;left:0;bottom:0;top:0;right:0;z-index:-1;'></div></div>
    <div     id='innerText57__Text57' data-id='innerText57' style='' data-type="text" class='dataTypeText  inner_text innerText57   text_editor_resets' ><div  class='innerText57_ContentDiv'><p class="Normal ospfxwcab77201c03f1832e7a1003cb178d5c3ossfx">The Paragraph element is a way to create long, uniform sections of text in your design and is suitable for descriptions.</p></div><div class='text_caption_background' style='background-color:transparent;opacity:1;position:absolute;left:0;bottom:0;top:0;right:0;z-index:-1;'></div></div>
```

Comment: have you tried adding a media query in your css to force overriding defaults?

Comment: i guess this could be done @PHClaus but in the code webydo generates it doesn't seem like they use regular media query to define when to switch views so i wouldn't know how to override those